# DC-DC step up and step down converter for a solar panel

Tags: usb, solar-cell, converter, 5v

I have a 1W [solar panel](https://www.amazon.de/Zimo-Ladeger%C3%A4t-Solarmodul-Solarzelle-verschiedenen/dp/B01AEH7HMM/) that will output about from 0 to 7V (7V in full sun). I want to power up a small USB gadget with it. I need a device that is a step up converter when panel's voltage is under 5V and step down converter when the voltage is over 5V. Does it exist?

For now I only have this step up [converter](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00NQ8FJ6S/).
Maybe I can use it with a [5.1V zener](http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/5w-zener-diode-5-1-to-51v/17330) diode so I won't care about when the voltage is over 5V?

Comment: The name is buck-boost converter.

Comment: like this? https://www.amazon.de/XL6009-Adjust-Voltage-Converter-Module/dp/B013QUNQVU/

Comment: @EugeneSh. please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I see most convertors are using 6009 IC. One module has two ICs like this. Does it mean it is better? https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01IP909GW